# How to update anonymous objects property using LINQ and Contains

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I have two anonymous object list as follows

```
 var persons = people.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Year = x.Value });

 var years = yrs.Select(y => new { OldYear = y.Name, NewYear = y.Value });
```

Now I wanted to update the persons list, such that if any of the person's year exists in the years list as old year, then the year property needs to be updated with the NewYear value.

This is how I'm currently doing the old school way

```
 foreach(var p in persons)
                {
                    if(years.Any(a => a.OldYear == p.Year))
                    {
                        p.Year = ages.Single(a => a.OldYear == p.Year).NewYear;  --> error
                    }
                }
```

This doesn't work, coz compiler complains that I can't set the readonly property 'Year' of the anonymous type.

Is there a simpler/better way in LINQ to update the person list based on another anonymous list in one LINQ statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform further Select:

```
var people = from p in persons
    let year = ages.Any(a=>a.NewYear==p.Year) ? ages.Single(a => a.OldYear == p.Year).NewYear : p.Year
    select new { Name = p.Name, Year = year; };
```

Comment: That changes the in-memory data; it doesn't allow the data in the database to be updated.

Comment: but this selecting only persons whose ages exist in the ages list (which btw updated the Q to be called years to be more clear). but I also want to select all the persons from the original list whose ages are not contained in the ages list. Your statement filters persons which isnot what I wanted.

Comment: @MarcinZablocki Yes, if there were I'd have downvoted this answer.  It looks like it could plausibly be a LINQ query that is querying the database.  The specific mention of updating the existing content rather than creating a new sequence however *is* stated explicitly in the question, and that would be the most compelling explanation for that requirement.

Comment: @Servy good point, which also got me a question to look for - is this possible to update database with the usage of anonymous types & linq?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki No.  Well, at least not with the providers I know of.  It's theoretically possible for someone to create a provider that supported it.

Comment: @Servy so when author of the question used anonymous type, there was automatically no option for usage of his code in context of database, am I right?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki If he knew that, yes.  If he didn't know that, then the solution to his problem would necessitate not using an anonymous type.  That would be the answer.